# UseEffect not returning response onMount

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios, react-testing-library

I am running a test on page load and refresh. It is working well but the test is returning 0;

below is my code;

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (navigator.geolocation) {


    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
    } else {
      setError("Your browser doesn't support geolocation");
    }
    const fetchLocations = async () => {
      if(currentPos.latitude!==undefined && currentPos.longitude!==undefined) {
          try {
          const response =  await instance
              .get("/explore", {
                params: {
                  ll: `${currentPos.latitude},${currentPos.longitude}`
                }
              })
            console.log(response.data.response.groups[0].items);
            setLocations(response.data.response.groups[0].items);
            setError('')
            setLoading(false)
          } catch (error) {
            setError('Error getting data');
            setLoading(false)
          }
        }
      }
    fetchLocations()
      }, [currentPos.latitude, currentPos.longitude]);
```

and my test:
What is happening here is on first mount `loading...` is available.  On fetching data from the API is expected `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` to be 1 instead of returning 0.

```
it("renders location venues on currentlocation ", async () => {
  const {getByText, container} = render(<Venues />);
  getByText('Loading...')

  await axiosMock.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(() =>
    Promise.resolve({ data: {response } })
  )

  expect(axiosMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
  await waitForElement(() =>
    container,
    expect(axiosMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  );
});
```

How can I fix this test and make it work properly?

Comment: useEffect(()=>{ ... your code ...}, [])
this is the called once when the component is mounted.
useEffect(()=>{..       ..}, [currentPos.latitude, currentPos.longitude] )
is called only when currentPos.latitude or currentPos.longitude is changed.

Comment: I have a geolocation function that populate the latitude and longitude on page load or refresh
 ```const getPosition = ({coords}) => {
    setCurrentPos({latitude: coords.latitude, longitude: coords.longitude});
  }```
This should definitely get the latitude and longitude respectively.